# Are "where can I find the source of this dead project"-questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In particular, I'm looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_(software) which should be available at chandlerproject.org but that website is down, and I can only find the executable online on other websites; not the open source code.

Would a question like this be on topic?

Comment: is this it? https://github.com/owenmorris/chandler ?

Comment: Related questions: [Is asking for the canonical location of source code on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1220/60) · [Is it on topic to ask where to download specific drivers?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1224/60)

Comment: I could recommend a web based solution to find old archival copies of websites. :P http://web.archive.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO not really. Software recommendations is meant for finding solutions to a problem - and much of the guidelines for questions revolve around asking the *right* questions and letting the community find answers that fit. "I need to drive in nails into a piece of wood" type problems as opposed to "where do I find a 3 1/4 pound left handed tack hammer".

In this case the problem you're trying to solve isn't "I need a PIM which solves these problems and is open source", its "I can't find the source for this PIM, help!".

I'd add, I'm not sure if its what you're looking for but there's a link to the source on github *right at the bottom* of the wikipedia page you linked.

Comment: Turns out, I'm blind. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying "where can I find the source of project X" is on-topic? That would really surprise me, as it neither fits our `help/on-topic` page nor our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/185).

Comment: no. I am saying it is not

Comment: OK, then you have my vote. Your hammer got me confused :)

Answer (score 4):

This question is on-topic on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) IF:

- The source code is extremely hard to find
- You could not find it even after spending an hour on Google
- It can't be found on popular source code sites like Sourceforge and Github either.

Reference: https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/where-is-old-arcane-project-now-maintained-maybe-as-a-fork-under-another-name